# GeoServer - How to display Ortho ortho (JP2 file) when georeference of each file are located in jgw file

Tags: geoserver, georeferencing, jpeg-2000

I wouldlike to create a layer with all my tiles of ortho (jpeg2000). The problem here is the georeference of each jpeg2000 file are in .jgw file. When I try to add this on geoserver, I have always the same error:

[image]

```
Caused by: org.opengis.referencing.operation.OperationNotFoundException: Aucune transformation du système "EngineeringCRS[Wildcard 2D cartesian plane in metric unit]" vers "GeographicCRS[WGS84(DD)]" n'est disponible.
```

Comment: You have no projection, either use gdal to convert to GeoTIFF or add a.prj file to each one

Comment: @IanTurton Ok thanks for you're answer !  How can I convert to GeoTIFF ? By using 
Image data sources then GeoTIFF - Tagged Image File Format with Geographic information ?

Comment: Usually I would use gdal_translate

Answer (score -1):

Your JP2k files are missing their projection information. There are two solutions

1. add a `.prj` file to each file. 
   I wrote a [program](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1680425) and a [blog post](https://blog.ianturton.com/geotools,/projections,/itches/2017/10/20/adding-prj.html) about how to add `.prj` files to large groups of rasters to solve this problem.
2. Convert your files to a format with the projection and georeferencing metadata included in it. Normally, the GeoServer community recommend you use GeoTiffs with compression, tiling and overveiws.